# Benchmarking complex queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssms

I have two queries that do the same, moderately complicated task. One joins sub-queries, one uses a table variable. I'd like to run test such that I see the total time taken by repeated execution.

However, several I have several issues with a simple method I found online:

```
DECLARE variables
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

/* Benchmark query 1 */
/* Benchmark query 2 */

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

I extended this with `WHILE`-loops.

#### Issues:

- Timer ticks off every loop (query execution) and every sub 'procedure' rather than the whole while statement.
- A temporary table with a row that has a `UNIQUE` column throws errors from the second iteration forward as I insert the same items again.
- SSMS shows every result set in the results-window, which is not the point of the benchmark.
- <strike>Most of the timings of near 0 ms indicate that there is some caching going on.</strike> (probably due to many sub phases in the table variable query being logged one by one)
- Variables declared in the queries produce an error when declared again.

When I started looking into benchmarking, I assumed there would be an easy way to execute queries from file repeatedly and time the execution. The only thing I found was SQLCmd, but it didn't quite seem like all I needed, I'd prefer to do all this inside SSMS.

So, is the process I'm describing above possible? If so, what would I need? If not, what is the standard way of benchmarking more complicated queries than just a single `SELECT`?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, as I'm quite the novice at this game.

Comment: If you want to benchmark without letting the Relational Engine Optimizer optimize/cache your plans then you may want to clear the plan cache --> https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/

Comment: Have you tried a Profiler trace?